# Google Maps V3: Hexagon grid - Error with setWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making hexagon grid for my game based on Google Map v3 and got a problem.

After I click in one hexagon are showing differents values, not one the same as for marker inside of the all hexagon.

The right value is showing just in the left down corner of quarter hexagon.
The value of coord_slug is making based on coordinates lat, lng.

What I have to do hexagon and marker values being the same ?
In this way 55.3,14.8 for upper and 55.25,1485 for down hexagon.

I need those values in a game for downloading dates from database.

The part responsible for displaying the value:

```
function set_window(event) {
    // Set Parameters
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    var coord_slug = (Math.round(lat * 20) / 20) + ',' + (Math.round(lng * 20) / 20);
alert(coord_slug);
}
```

The working part of the script here:

```js
function round_down(n) {
    if (n > 0) {
      return Math.ceil(n / 0.05) * 0.05;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

var map;
var pointCount = 0;
var locations = [];
var gridWidth = 3660; // hex tile size in meters
var bounds;

var places = [
  [55.3, 14.8],
  [55.25, 14.85],
]

var SQRT3 = 1.73205080756887729352744634150587236;

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {center: {lat: 55.27, lng: 14.8}, zoom: 10});
  
  // Adding a marker just so we can visualize where the actual data points are.
  // In the end, we want to see the hex tile that contain them
  places.forEach(function(place, p){
    
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: place[0], lng: place[1]});
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng, 
  map: map})
  marker.addListener('click', set_window);
    
    // Fitting to bounds so the map is zoomed to the right place
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  });
  
  
  
  // Now, we draw our hexagons! (or try to)
  locations = makeBins(places);
  
  locations.forEach(function(place, p){
    drawHorizontalHexagon(map, place, gridWidth);
  })
    
    
});

  
  function drawHorizontalHexagon(map, position, radius){
    var coordinates = [];
    for(var angle= 0;angle < 360; angle+=60) {
       coordinates.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(position, radius, angle));    
    }

    // Construct the polygon.
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coordinates,
        position: position,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        geodesic: true
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
    polygon.addListener('click', set_window);
}

// Below is my attempt at porting binner.py to Javascript.
// Source: https://github.com/coryfoo/hexbins/blob/master/hexbin/binner.py

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  console.log(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  result =  Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
  console.log("Distance: ", result);
  return
}

function nearestCenterPoint(value, scale){
    div = value / (scale/2);
    console.log("div", div);
    mod = value % (scale/2);
    console.log("mod", mod);
    
    if(div % 2 == 1){
      increment = 1;
    } else{
      increment = 0;
    }
    
    rounded = scale / 2 * (div + increment);
    
    if(div % 2 === 0){
      increment = 1;
    } else{
      increment = 0;
    }
    
    rounded_scaled = scale / 2 * (div + increment);
    
    result = [rounded, rounded_scaled]
    console.log("nearest centerpoint to", value, result);
    return result;
}

function makeBins(data){
  bins = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(place, p){
    x = place[0];
    y = place[1];
    
    console.log("Original location:", x, y);
    
    px_nearest = nearestCenterPoint(x, gridWidth);
    
    py_nearest = nearestCenterPoint(y, gridWidth * SQRT3);
    
    z1 = distance(x, y, px_nearest[0], py_nearest[0]);
    z2 = distance(x, y, px_nearest[1], py_nearest[1]);
    
    if(z1 > z2){
      bin = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: px_nearest[0], lng: py_nearest[0]});
       console.log("Final location:", px_nearest[0], py_nearest[0]);
    } else {
      bin = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: px_nearest[1], lng: py_nearest[1]});
       console.log("Final location:", px_nearest[1], py_nearest[1]);
    }
  
    bins.push(bin);
    
  })
  return bins;
}
function set_window(event) {
    // Set Parameters
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    var coord_slug = (Math.round(lat * 20) / 20) + ',' + (Math.round(lng * 20) / 20);
alert(coord_slug);
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:80vh;">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Additional link:
[The working part of the script in Plunger](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFMiDxS1XnqB0OcOFlla?p=preview)

Comment: I am not sure I got the question right... Can you try explaining again? The values in the alert boxes are the same for marker and polygon (?) for me, is it not?

Comment: No. when I click on different places on the polygon then says different values. Example it should be 55.3,14.8 but is showing 55.3,14.85 (right side of upper hexagon)

Comment: So when you click on the Polygon you want to alert the center position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a `position` attribute to your Polygons, which seems to be what you want to display...

So you can replace the following

```
polygon.addListener('click', set_window);
```

By this:

```
polygon.addListener('click', function() {

  var polyPosition = this.position.lat() + ', ' + this.position.lng();
  alert(polyPosition);
});
```